# How to add conditional statement inside react fragment

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Inside of the react fragment I have to add conditional statement. On basis of the conditional statement,  return what expected

```
return (
   <React.Fragment>
      <Toolbar
         pageTitle={i18next.t('TITLE')}
         iconButtons={this.state.icons}
         {this.props.abc && this.props.abc.operation ?(
          moreButton={moreButton}
         ):null}
      />
```

if this.props.abc.operation is present then only show morebutton if not show only iconbuttons this is my condition and above is the code i tried. any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <>
  <Toolbar
     pageTitle={i18next.t('TITLE')}
     iconButtons={this.state.icons}
     moreButton={this.props.abc && this.props.abc.operation && moreButton}
  />
</>
```

Try to use this.

Comment: thanks for the response, @priyesh pandey

but unfortunately, this is not working, my doubt is can i able to access or use props inside react fragment or return statement!?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of conditional rendering you can do like below.

```
isAbcOperationExist = (args) => {
  if(args && args.operation){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Now inside component props:

```
   <Toolbar
     pageTitle={i18next.t('TITLE')}
     iconButtons={this.state.icons}
     showMoreButton={() => this.isAbcOperationExist(this.props.abc)}
   />
```

Based on result returned boolean value by method `isAbcOperationExist` you can show or hide moreButton

More Example:

Assumption this is class based component:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props)  
   }

   isAbcOperationExist = (args) => {
     if(args && args.operation) {
       return true;
     }
     return false;
   }
              
   render (){
     return (
       <Toolbar
         pageTitle={i18next.t('TITLE')}
         iconButtons={this.state.icons}
         moreButton={moreButton}
         showMoreButton={() => this.isAbcOperationExist(this.props.abc)}
       />
      )
     }
    }
```

For Toolbar Component assuming it as functional base component:

```
const Toolbar = ({pageTitle, iconButtons, showMoreButton, moreButton}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      {
        showMoreButton ? <button onClick={moreButton}>Show More</button> : null
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: showMoreButton={() => isAbcOperationExist(this.props.abc)}

seems like an syntax error, where are we suppose to pass 
morebutton function here..

before it was like moreButton={moreButton} 


//calling morebutton function here

Comment: Assuming if you are using class-based component you need to add this keyword as like this.isAbcOperationExist(this.props.abc) i have edited above code example also. And If you want to pass moreButton option you can pass moreButton={moreButton} with another props showMoreButton with boolean value. So that with showMoreButton boolean value you can check whether you want to render show more button or not. I will added another example in above comment also.

Comment: HI 
@ Sujit Libi and @Airo

Thank you so much for your solution, considering all your inputs

I modified the code like below and it worked, completely taken out toolbar component from react fragment and according to the logic tollbar compo is showing what needed

  let toolbar = (
   <Toolbar
    iconButtons={this.state.icons}
   />
  );

  if (this.props.abc && this.props.abc.operation){
   toolbar = (
    <Toolbar
     iconButtons={this.state.icons}
     moreButton={moreButton}
    />
   );
  }

Answer (score 0):

React Fragment has nothing to do with this. You also can't manipulate component props like this. The idea would be to have a single prop for iconButtons and moreButton and and do the logic what to show inside Toolbar component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).